# Active contour initialization

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to segment an image

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/wu33pl.jpg]

I want to take the two contours with blue

[image: Wanted contours image]

Anyone with an idea which technique can i use for this kind of segmentation?

The problem is that i want to use Active contours for segmentation and i want automatic initialization of active contours in this kind of images .For this purpose i have to find a way to put inside the contours i draw an initial contour.Any idea of how can make this ,any charactiristic that you can see and i can take(texture,etc)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing it would be to threshold the image, locate the objects with `regionprops`, keep only those of interest (here, with an area criteria) and find the contour with `bwboundaries`.

In practice, this gives:

```
% Define threshold
th_BW = 100;

% Read image
img = imread('myimage.jpg');

% Get objects and filter them
R = regionprops(img>th_BW, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList');
I = find([R.Area]>1000 & [R.Area]<10000);

% Get contours
C = cell(numel(I),1);
for i = 1:numel(I)   
    BW = img*0;
    BW(R(I(i)).PixelIdxList) = 1;
    tmp = bwboundaries(BW);
    C{i} = tmp{1};
end

% Display
imshow(img)
hold on
plot(C{1}(:,2), C{1}(:,1), 'Linewidth', 2);
plot(C{2}(:,2), C{2}(:,1), 'Linewidth', 2);
```

And here is the result:

[image: Result image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of MATLAB, try the [Image Segmenter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-segmentation-using-the-image-segmenter-app.html) app.

Comment: Thank you Crazy Rat and Dima .The problem is that i want to use Active contours and i want automatic initialization in this kind of images .Any idea of how to take an initial  contour inside this images ,any charactiristic that you can see and i can take(texture,etc)?